# Storing application logs for a day

Tags: linux, unix, logging, log4j

I have an application running in Production. Where we create the logs file. The maximum count of log file is set to 10 and maximum debug write is set to some value such that when a log file becomes of 6MB a new log file is created..

So, we have logs rolling over with file names like :-

```
<file_name>.log
<file_name>.log.1
<file_name>.log.2
...
<file_name>.log.10
```

What my problem is that only logs for **15 minutes** can be found in these **10 log files**. 
I know I can update my code base to use DailyRollingFileAppender. But what I'm looking for is a short term solution to store logs for a day such that it can be done without any code changes or minimal code/configuartion changes. For exmaple may be I can acheive this via some cron job or linux command.. etc.

Note:- I'm running this application on Linux OS in production.

Any quick help is highly appreciated.

~Thanks

Comment: `The maximum count of log file is set to 10 and maximum debug write is set to some value such that when a log file becomes of 6MB a new log file is created..`. So what you do after that? Mean it will overwrite the old logs form new one?

Comment: Yes!! Obviously. rollover will be more appropriate to say then overwrite. Logs rollover when file reaches max configured size.New logs are written to <file_name>.log file. and as its size increase its content is shifted to *.log.1... *.log.10 file... Simply, Old content gets removed and new content is rolled over.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this create a shell script and adding it to cron jobs.

```
NOW_DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M") 
cd /var/log/OLD_LOGS
mkdir /var/log/OLD_LOGS/$NOW_DATE

cd /var/log/
mv server.log.* /var/log/OLD_LOGS/$NOW_DATE/
mv *.zip /var/log/OLD_LOGS/$NOW_DATE/
cp server.log /var/log/OLD_LOGS/$NOW_DATE/

cd /var/log/OLD_LOGS/$NOW_DATE
x=$(ls -l |wc -l)
if [ $x -le 1 ] then
SUBJECT="There is an issue with generating server log - less number of files"
EMAIL="support@abc.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/errormsg.txt"

/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
fi

cd /var/log/OLD_LOGS/
zip -r $NOW_DATE.zip $NOW_DATE
rm -r -f $NOW_DATE

find /var/log/ -type f -mtime +180 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application tries to create .log.11 and if it overwrites the old ones as per the script conditions, there is no possibility of having the logs for a day. 
What i understand is application logging is much such that all the 10 files have loggings for last 15 minutes and the new lines are again overwritten on them.

Application logic should be modified to make sure it captures a day logs. Also, please make sure to zip the files at regular intervals so that you can save some disk space.